# Trouble adding Contacts to journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created a salesforce report, imported reported to marketing Cloud. Data extension is sendable.
I can see there is one record.
Mapped salesforceId to Contact Id in Contact Builder.

Created a journey, contact event selected same data extension.

Create an automation where I am firing the Fire Event once and "Fire event is pointing to same DE".

Trouble:

Contact not added to journey builder, what would be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple of obvious issues here.

Firstly, you shouldn't of "mapped salesforceId to Contact Id in Contact Builder". Contact ID is a system defined identifier when the Contact record is created. You should be mapping to the Contact Key. In fact, I'm not sure how you could have done this as SalesforceId is an alphanumeric string but the Contact ID is numeric.

Secondly, it sounds like you have created the relationship to the Contact Record in an Attribute Group, not a Population. If you did so, they should be injected into the Journey.

However, please be aware that by design, it's not recommended to create individual Populations for each Event Source DE. The Population should be linked to your main DE containing your Contacts, then use the Event Source DE to identify which Contacts should be injected into the Journey.

Comment: Yes you are right the relation is in between Contact Key with salesforceid.
Is it necessary to create relationship in  contact record ?

Comment: Yes, at a minimum you will need a relationship in a Population to the Contact Record from your Contacts DE, however you don't necessarily need to include your Event Source DE in an Attribute Group.

Comment: Thanks very much . Another small question. Do I need to configure/customise Data Source as well ?

Comment: No, this is certainly not a prerequisite.